# Joint distribution

Tags: probability

This might be a trivial question.

> Let $X_{1}$ be a random variable and let $X_{2}$ be a random variable with the same probability
>   distribution as the random variable $Y_{2}$.

**Question:** Can I conclude that the joint distributions of the random variable ($X_{1}, Y_{2}$) and the random variable ($X_{1}, X_{2}$) are the same?

---

I think it makes sense (since we can interpret $X_{2}$ and $Y_{2}$ to be one random variable that describes the same), but I'm not feeling confident enough to state this as a true statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  For a counterexample, consider the probability space for flipping two independent, fair coins.  Let $X_1$ and $Y_2$ both be the outcome of the first coin flip, and let $X_2$ be the outcome of the second coin flip.